# iPhone - Insert password checking

Tags: iphone, ios

I have navigation-based application with first RootViewController.

I wanna to protect it with password like lock screen. 
I've already code of password checking.

But I don't know how to

1) **Insert my CheckPasswordView first before RootViewController.**

2) **Require to enter the password every time my application reopens from suspend.**

Update:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */

    CheckPasswordViewController *vc = [[CheckPasswordViewController alloc] 
                                       initWithNibName:@"CheckPasswordViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.title = @"Enter password";       

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];    

    [vc release]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [UIApplicationDelegate's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786) `applicationDidBecomeActive` message. In that delegate (function) you can put code to make your `CheckPasswordView` active and ask user for password before resuming the application. From the documentation:

> This method is called to let your application know that it moved from
>   the inactive to active state. This can occur because your application
>   was launched by the user or the system. Applications can also return
>   to the active state if the user chooses to ignore an interruption
>   (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) that sent the
>   application temporarily to the inactive state.

There are other methods in this delegate you can take a look at to implement what you need.

Comment: Thank you! It Works. I show my PasswordCheckView in applicationDidBecomeActive message. After correct enter password I pass to main program. But if I reopen my app several times without entering code, I found, that I'm offering to enter password several times.

Comment: There is still a small security breach here, given that you do not want to expose anyone to the root view without entering a password - because the CheckPasswordViewController is being animated in, it may give a chance to take a quick screenshot of the root view. What I would recommend is doing this in the applicationWillResignActive: method of your AppDelegate class.

Comment: You may want to consider doing this on `applicationWillResignActive` to account for the case where the user double-clicks the home button to bring up the multitasking drawer. Your app is still visible, but inactive.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. But how to prevent problem with showing several CheckPasswordViews, that I wrote above?

Comment: It means how to understand, that my current view before making app inactive was CheckPasswordView ?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are pushing the view controller into place. That's why it is being shown multiple times. If you want to prevent that, present the view controller modally.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference?

Comment: That's OK, I've understood. I just open my view with [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:checkPasswordView animated:YES];    Thanks a lot!